# If $u_k $ are all positive, and $\sum_{k>n} u_k < u_n $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $u_k $ are all positive, and $\sum_{k>n} u_k \leq c u_n $ for $c>0$ and for all n. Prove there exits $b$, and $a $ positive and $0 <a <1$ such that ,
$u_n\leq b a^n $ ?.

My partial solution .

It's easy to show $u_n\leq c^n u_1$  for $n>1$

I am not sure how to pass to the case $n=1$, and how can I argue that $c <1$?

Comment: Note that one won't be able to prove that $c$ itself is less than $1$: consider $u_n = (2/3)^n$, for which $c$ cannot be taken smaller than $2$ but which still satisfies the conditions in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the sum
$$ S_n = \sum_{k=n}^\infty u_k, $$ then $S_1\geq S_2\geq \cdots\geq S_n$ and $u_n=S_n-S_{n+1}$. The condition $\sum_{k>n} u_k \leq c u_n$ becomes
$S_{n+1}\leq c(S_n-S_{n+1})$ or equivalently $S_{n+1}\leq \frac{c}{c+1}S_n$. Therefore
$$ u_n
\leq  S_n \leq \frac{c}{c+1}S_{n-1} \leq \left(\frac{c}{c+1}\right)^2S_{n-2}
\leq \cdots \leq \left(\frac{c}{c+1}\right)^{n-1}S_1=ba^n$$
by choosing
$$ a= \frac{c}{c+1},\ b = \frac{c+1}{c}S_1.$$